# Making view transient does not seem to work in JSF 2

Tags: java, session, jsf-2

I have a home page that is written in JSF 2.2. It uses a public template that is shared by many other pages. I don't want to include `<f:view transient="true">` in the public template because I want to make only this particular home page as transient.

Now I have this code in my home page

```
    <f:view transient="true">   
    <ui:define name="content">
               .....
            <h:commandLink value="#{msg['homepage.createaccount']}"
            action="#{homepageController.createNewAccount()}" />

     </ui:define>
     </f:view>
```

now HomepageController is a named session bean.

```
 @Named
  @Session
 public class HomepageController   {

  //code here

   }
```

**The `<f:view = "transient">` does not seem to work. Is it because the controller is Session scoped ?**

The controller is session scoped because while loading the first page, we fetch several important lists that are used later by many parts of application.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not seem to work`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: By 'it does not work', I meant, that when I click on Create Account link, I still get a session expired error.